# Why is the WM_CLASS of Firefox called Navigator?

Tags: firefox, xorg

According to https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_CLASS:

> The two strings, respectively, are:
>
> - A string that names the particular instance of the application to which the client that owns this window belongs. Resources that are specified by instance name override any resources that are specified by class name. Instance names can be specified by the user in an operating-system specific manner. On POSIX-conformant systems, the following conventions are used:
>   [...]
> - A string that names the general class of applications to which the client that owns this window belongs. Resources that are specified by class apply to all applications that have the same class name. Class names are specified by the application writer. Examples of commonly used class names include: "Emacs", "XTerm", "XClock", "XLoad", and so on.

The `WM_CLASS` of Firefox is "Navigator", "firefox", which from what i understand does not match the description of what `WM_CLASS`. It is possible that Navigator was a previous name for Firefox, but I am unsure about why Navigator is part of the `WM_CLASS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kills me.  Oh man you make me feel old.

Yes indeed, WM_CLASS of Firefox is "Navigator" for a reason.

***I am going to give you a history lesson you never wanted.***

Firefox was once "[Netscape Navigator](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/is-it-true-that-netscape-navigator-eventually-became-mozilla-firefox)" which once upon a time was based on the Mosaic browser which goes back even farther.  Not the source code.. but the design.

It was written even before Windows 95 (or internet explorer) were released.

Once apon a time, there was an open game to who was going to win the browser war.

Mozilla/Navigator/Firefox(later) was clearly the contender to be the leader in this field.

So two things happened..

1. Netscape decided that they were going to re-write 100% of the code.  The rewrite was riddled with bugs.  This killed any chance to win at this point in time.
2. Microsoft paid Mosaic to write internet explorer.  In the VERY early days, internet explorer wasn't a bloated POS and see #1 above.
3. Microsoft bundled IE with their OS making it easy for people to use the web without even needing to download an additional piece of software to do it.  On a dial-up modem, this was critical.  They got sued for this and lost in Europe but that is another story.
4. After losing the war, the Netscape code was put up as open source called "firefox" and took a while to work the kinks out of (see #1) but is now (I think?) the only real alternative to Chrome.

Anyone, please feel free to edit my commentary.  I was indeed in the trenches through this but perhaps my memory is skewed.

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson! As a follow up, do you know when Mozilla took over the Firefox project, or were they there from the start?

Comment: The project name changed from Netscape to Firefox. i believe it's always been Mozilla.